# Why can't you use functions on captured group (and is there a workaround)?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, if I do something like:

`"start.content.end".replace(/start.(.*).end/,"$1".toUpperCase()`

I get: `content`, not `CONTENT` as expected.

But it works with string literals, e.g.:

`"start.content.end".replace(/start.(.*).end/,"$1".toUpperCase() + "_lowercase".toUpperCase())`

`"content_LOWERCASE"`

Why is this the case, and is there any way to work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.toUpperCase` and `.toLowerCase` strings are being parsed *immediately*, and then the interpreter replaces `$#`s in the result with the capture groups. This:

```
.replace(/start.(.*).end/,"$1".toUpperCase())
```

is just

```
.replace(/start.(.*).end/,"$1")
```

and the `.replace` gets passed that `$1` and replaces it with the first capture group.

Similarly:

```
"start.content.end".replace(/start.(.*).end/,"$1".toUpperCase() + "_lowercase".toUpperCase())
```

is just

```
"start.content.end".replace(/start.(.*).end/,"$1".toUpperCase() + "_lowercase".toUpperCase())
"start.content.end".replace(/start.(.*).end/,"$1"               + "_lowercase".toUpperCase())
"start.content.end".replace(/start.(.*).end/,"$1" + "_lowercase".toUpperCase())
"start.content.end".replace(/start.(.*).end/,"$1" + "_LOWERCASE")
"start.content.end".replace(/start.(.*).end/,"$1_LOWERCASE")
```

So `"$1_LOWERCASE"` gets passed to `.replace`, which parses it, sees the `$1`, and replaces that `$1` with the capture group.

Both of your snippets are fundamentally doing the same thing - a plain string gets parsed, then gets passed to `.replace`, which replaces `$#`s inside it.

If you want to be able to perform particular actions on capture groups - to do anything other than plain string interpolation with `$#`s, use a function instead, eg:

```js
console.log(
  "start.content.end"
    .replace(
      /start.(.*).end/,
      (match, g1) => g1.toUpperCase()
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that's how it works. `.replace` has to receive a *function reference* that it can call with thr specified arument.

Your attempt would call a method on the literal string `$1` itself, making it `$1` (there are no uppercaseable characters), and *then* passes that to `.replace`. `.replace` isn't even aware (and can't be made aware by design) of that `.toUpperCase`!

The same thing happens with:

```
"$1".toUpperCase() + "_lowercase".toUpperCase()
```

...which is pretty much the same as writing:

```
"$1_LOWERCASE"
```

...because `.toUpperCase` acts on the *replacer string* itself, not the *selection matched by it* by `.replace`

To make the *selection represented by* `$1` uppercased, you have to pass a replacer callback to `.replace`, that receives it as an argument and lets you hook into the logic:

```
"start.content.end".replace(/start.(.*).end/, (match, firstCapturing) => firstCapturing.toUpperCase())
```